# Set buttons position when page is resized

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have this html code which I use with Bootstrap:

```
<div class="cell-xs-10 cell-md-6">
  <div>
    <div class="text-center offset-top-20">
       <input id="buy" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
       <input id="buy" type="sell" class="btn btn-primary">
    </di>
  <div>
<div>
```

When I resize the web page and reduce the width the buttons are moved and the second goes below the first. Is there some way to keep their position and keep them horizontally?

Comment: What you want to say, I didn't understand. please briefly explain it so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

If the width of the container element is not sufficient for both buttons, it is not possible. Try to give a bigger width to the container element for smaller screens with a media query, if the size of the screen allows it ofcourse.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using CSS properties at element level to provide fix position to the button.
like

```
<input id="buy" style="position : absolute;" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
<input id="buy" style="position : absolute;" type="sell" class="btn btn-primary">
```

Or at class level like

```
btn-primary {
     position : absolute;
}
```

Comment: Well, the first button wen under the firsts button.

Comment: try position : relative